# Xcode 6 changes UILabel position when restarting

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I have a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell in Interface Builder. It changes position every time I close Xcode and open the project again. This also happens with the size of the UIImageView (it seems to double in size). It's definitely a bug with Xcode, but are there any workarounds at this moment? Every time Xcode crashes,  I have to spend about 30 minutes-1 hour resetting all UILabels and UIImageView sizes upon opening the project.

Comment: I assume that you don't have enough layout constraints.

Comment: @dasdom I'm not using autolayout. Using autoresizing masks.

Comment: You should use auto layout. It helps a lot!

Comment: @dasdom autolayout doesn't make sense in my project.

Comment: I doubt that. But never mind. I think I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: Can you post the screenshoot?

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3703182/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-21%20at%205.28.50%20AM.png

Comment: @Ninja Are you setting this in a custom UITableViewCell? seem like you just glue it in IB.

Comment: I am doing a dynamic prototype. What do you mean glue it in IB? Everytime I move the UILabels, the position resets whenever I close and re-open Xcode.

Comment: Here's an example project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xza9ia56wa9avd/tableviewTest.zip?dl=0 try resizing the uilabel to 300 width. close the project and re-open the project, you'll see the uilabel magically resized to 620.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I noted it occurs when an outlet is in UITableview or UICollectionView and has given auto resizing mask as flexible height / width.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with switches. Every time I open Xcode I get Misplaced Views warnings for all the switches saying that it expects x="738" and the actual is x="538". At first I thought I was making a mistake, then I speculated that xCode was not saving the positions. I even opened the storyboard with an editor and changed every switch position but when xCode opens the storyboard again all of the switch settings have reverted to x="538". What is going on? Is this an xCode bug?

Comment: I just noticed that one switch remembered its position and the difference

Comment: Investigation of the storyboard source showed that there the good switches all have <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=regular"> whereas the "bad" switches have <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=regular" misplaced="YES">. I'm going to remove misplaced="YES" from the bad switches to see whether this helps. I'll report back if it does.